# insert_id me devuelve 0 en INSERT MySQLI / PHP

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mariadb, php5

Tengo problemas al insertar datos en una tabla con php, en mi servidor local funciona correctamente el código y el ->insert_id regresa el valor correcto pero cuando lo subí a un servidor de 000webhost el ->insert_id esta regresando 0 apesar de que el id_evento este con AUTO INCREMENT incluso en la información de la tabla eventos el indice automático dice que el siguiente es 1
[image: Información de la tabla]

Hace la conexión correctamente, las tablas están configuradas exactamente igual que en mi servidor local ya que solo exporte las tablas de mi servidor local y lo importe en la base de datos de 000webhost

**CODIGO PHP:**

```
<?php
include_once 'funciones/funciones.php';
$titulo = $_POST['titulo_evento'];
$lugar = $_POST['lugar_evento'];
$link = $_POST['link_evento'];
//obtiene la fecha
$fecha = $_POST['fecha_evento'];
$fecha_formateada = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha));
//obtiene la hora
$hora = $_POST['hora_evento'];
$hora_formateada = date('H:i:s', strtotime($hora));

if ($_POST['registro'] == 'nuevo') {
  try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO eventos (nombre_evento, fecha_evento, hora_evento, lugar_evento, link_evento) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $titulo, $fecha_formateada, $hora_formateada, $lugar, $link);
    $stmt->execute();
    $id_insertado = $stmt->insert_id;
    if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'Exito',
        'id_insertado' => $id_insertado
      );
    } else {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error'
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    $respuesta = array(
      'respuesta' => $e->getMessage()
    );
  }
  die(json_encode($respuesta));
}
?>
```

**Codigo AJAX:**

```
$('#guardar-registo').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var datos = $(this).serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      data: datos,
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var resultado = data;
        if (resultado.respuesta == 'Exito') {
          const Toast = Swal.mixin({
            toast: true,
            position: 'top-end',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 3000,
            customClass: 'alerta'
          });

            Toast.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Se guardo correctamente'
          })
        } else {
          const Toast = Swal.mixin({
            toast: true,
            position: 'top-end',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 3000,
            customClass: 'alerta'
          });

            Toast.fire({
            type: 'error',
            title: '¡Hubo un error!'
          })
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

**Codigo HTML**

```
           <div class="box-body">
              <!-- form start -->
              <form role="form" name="guardar-registo" id="guardar-registo" method="post" action="modelo-evento.php">
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre">Titulo del evento:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo_evento" name="titulo_evento" placeholder="Ingresa el titulo del evento">
                  </div>
                  <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Hora del evento:</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control hora" name="hora_evento">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="aviso-container">
                        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                        <span class="formato-aviso"></i>HH:MM AM/PM</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Fecha del evento:</label>
                    <div class="input-group date">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="fecha" name="fecha_evento">
                    </div>
                    <div class="aviso-container">
                      <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                      <span class="formato-aviso"></i>MM/DD/AAAA</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre">Lugar del evento:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lugar_evento" name="lugar_evento" placeholder="Ingresa el lugar del evento">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre">Link del evento:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="link_evento" name="link_evento" placeholder="Ingresa el lugar del evento">
                    <div class="aviso-container">
                      <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                      <span class="formato-aviso"></i>www.facebook.com/event/<ins>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ins></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-footer -->
                <div class="box-footer">
                  <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="nuevo">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="crear_registro">Añadir</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

[image: Lo que devuelve la consola]

**UPDATE:**
lo solucione con esta actualización al codigo.

```
if ($_POST['registro'] == 'nuevo') {
  try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO eventos (nombre_evento, fecha_evento, hora_evento, lugar_evento, link_evento, editado_evento) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now())');
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $titulo, $fecha_formateada, $hora_formateada, $lugar, $link);
    $stmt->execute();
    $id_insertado = $stmt->insert_id;
    if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'Exito',
        'id_insertado' => $id_insertado
      );
    } else {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error',
        'error' => mysqli_error($conn)
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    $respuesta = array(
      'respuesta' => $e->getMessage()
    );
  }
  die(json_encode($respuesta));
}
```

Comment: Esta comparación no es del todo segura: `if ($stmt->affected_rows) {`  porque el Manual de PHP dice que **`affected_rows` puede devolver también `-1` cuando hay error en la consulta**. Supongamos una consulta errónea debido a la violación de una restricción, podría devolver `-1` y entrar en la parte del `if` que considera que la consulta fue exitosa. Deberías más bien comparar si el valor es mayor que `0`, mediante: `if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {`, ahí sí sólo entrará cuando haya filas afectadas **realmente**. Si aún así no funciona, prueba también esto: `$id_insertado = $conn->insert_id;`

Comment: Hola ya lo solucione poniendo en el if($stmt->affected_rows > 0) pasa al else y en el else en el array() agregue 'error' => mysqli-mysqli_error($conn) me decía el error que cometí muchas gracias.